# How to replace many if's statements in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, simplify, code-cleanup

I am trying to make my code "cleaner". I have many functions with a lot of if-statements. How can I replace them?

I'm using 4 differents Hashtables that's why I have those ifs. The only thing changing is the hashtable name and the jList where I add the informations.

```
if(n.getCategorie().getNum() == Categorie.INTERNATIONAL.getNum())
                {
                    DefaultListModel dlm = (DefaultListModel) jListInternationales.getModel();
                    dlm.addElement(n.getTitre());
                    jListInternationales.setModel(dlm);
                    NewsInter.put(""+nNews, n);
                }
                else if(n.getCategorie().getNum() == Categorie.POLITIQUE.getNum())
                {
                    DefaultListModel dlm = (DefaultListModel) jListViePolitique.getModel();
                    dlm.addElement(n.getTitre());
                    jListViePolitique.setModel(dlm);
            NewsPolitique.put(""+nNews, n);
                }
                else if(n.getCategorie().getNum() == Categorie.RAGOT.getNum())
                {
                    DefaultListModel dlm = (DefaultListModel) jListRagotsEtPotins.getModel();
                    dlm.addElement(n.getTitre());
                    jListRagotsEtPotins.setModel(dlm);
            NewsRagot.put(""+nNews, n);
                }
                else if(n.getCategorie().getNum() == Categorie.SPORT.getNum())
                {
                    DefaultListModel dlm = (DefaultListModel) jListInfosSports.getModel();
                    dlm.addElement(n.getTitre());
                    jListInfosSports.setModel(dlm);
            NewsSport.put(""+nNews, n);
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference between the `if` branches comes from the `JList` reference. Since the code is repeated you should extract it into a separate method:

```
private void updateList(JList list) {
  DefaultListModel dlm = (DefaultListModel) list.getModel();
  dlm.addElement(n.getTitre());
  list.setModel(dlm);
}
```

After that the code becomes much cleaner:

```
if (n.getCategorie().getNum() == Categorie.INTERNATIONAL.getNum()) {
  updateList(jListInternationales);
} else if (n.getCategorie().getNum() == Categorie.POLITIQUE.getNum()) {
  updateList(jListViePolitique);
} // etc

NewsInter.put(""+nNews, n);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the HashTable is changing too. Adding another parameter with the hashtable could be good I think.

Comment: @Kazh probably yes, however `NewsInter.put(""+nNews, n);` could be extracted out of the `if` altogether since it's repeated in every `if` branch.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you're using enums. Enums may be compared by instance. Checking the numbers is not required.

Those can be used in a switch case. E.g.

```
switch (n.getCategorie()) {
case Categorie.INTERNATIONAL:
...
```

That removes some clutter, but not essentially the number of 'if' statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the if, else if, else if, ... structure by changing it to the switch() structure, it looks like this:

```java
switch(n.getCategorie().getNum()){
    case Categorie.INTERNATIONAL.getNum():
        DefaultListModel dlm = (DefaultListModel) jListInternationales.getModel();
        dlm.addElement(n.getTitre());
        jListInternationales.setModel(dlm);
        NewsInter.put(""+nNews, n);

        break;
    case Categorie.POLITIQUE.getNum():
        ...etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case, you can replace it by `Switch` statement.

This is the structure:

```
switch(value) {
  case x:
    // code block
    break;
  case y:
    // code block
    break;
  default:
    // code block
}
```

In your specific problem , this would be:

```
switch(n.getCategorie()) {
  case International:
    // your code
    break;
  case Politique:
    // code block
    break;
...

  default:
    // code block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Switch Case command which takes less memory while processing